# Can't link opengl libraries in makefile

Tags: c++, opengl, makefile

I am writing a hybrid program in Cpp + x86 assembly. The project consists of 3 files: main.cc, data.cc and a_t.asm. I'm stuck with a makefile (in which I am a total beginner) part. It looks like this:

```
CC=gcc
ASMBIN=nasm
CFLAGS=-m32 -Wall

all: main.o a_t.o
    $(CC) -m32 main.o a_t.o -lGL -lGLU -lglut 

a_t.o:
    $(ASMBIN) -f elf a_t.asm

main.o: main.cc data.cc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -g main.cc

clean:
    rm -rf *o main
```

upon make command I get the following:

```
gcc -m32 main.o a_t.o -lGL -lGLU -lglut 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGLU
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglut
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I've tried putting "-lGL -lGLU -lglut" part in different orders, but nothing have worked. I have all three libraries installed and working.
I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Does your code actually make use of functions in these libraries? Looks to me like you simply have only the runtime libraries installed, but not the header files and the link libraries. There's nothing wrong with your makefile.

Comment: Yes, it does. Looks like it stops working properly when i add an -m32 flag.

Comment: That means, then, that you don't have the 32 bit libraries installed.

Comment: Yes, it is working now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Makefiles can be a bit arcane, somewhat fussy to get right, and there's a lot of voodoo floating around about how to write them.  Here is a more reasonable, fixed-up makefile:

```
# Don't set CC=gcc, because it's not 1995 any more.
ASMBIN = nasm
# CFLAGS is for C, CXXFLAGS is for C++
# Also, let's put -g here
CXXFLAGS = -m32 -Wall -g
LDFLAGS = -m32

# Use pkg-config wherever possible
opengl_libs := -lglut $(shell pkg-config --libs gl glu)
opengl_cflags := $(shell pkg-config --cflags gl glu)

all: main

main: main.o a_t.o
    # Order of flags is important here!
    # We also have to use CXX instead of CC to avoid linker errors.
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(opengl_libs)

a_t.o:
    $(ASMBIN) -f elf a_t.asm

main.o: main.cc data.cc
    # Don't forget -c and -o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(opengl_cflags) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    # Should be *.o, not *o
    rm -rf *.o main

.PHONY: all clean
```

However, this probably won't fix the error you are running into.  You need to remember to install the development version of the OpenGL libraries.  On Debian-based systems, this would mean installing the following packages (for i386, of course):

- `libglu1-mesa-dev`
- `libgl1-mesa-dev`
- `freeglut3-dev`.

The `pkg-config` program is probably already installed.

Comment: Thank you for an extensive answer. Unfortunately, the problem still persists. I've got all the libraries you specified installed, checked it. Also, I discovered, that it only fails when i use -m32 flag which i can't really avoid using.

Comment: @GregoryZaika: Did you specifically install the i386 version of the packages?  It sounds like you didn't…

Comment: O my, I've completely overlooked that part in parenthesis about i386. My bad, could've get it much earlier.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was that using -m32 flag requires 32 bit libraries. As both people, to whom I'm extremely grateful, who answered me suggested, I should have installed the libraries, only the 32 bit versions of them.

```
libglu1-mesa-dev:i386
libgl1-mesa-dev:i386
freeglut3-dev:i386
```

For those who can use this answer, keep in mind that the install of i386 package, removes amd64, and vice versa. So don't forget to reinstall that packages with a `:amd64` specifier.